# Short Lived Transaction Cache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm in need of some short-lived transaction cache that behaves in a similar way to SQL Transaction. Where I would be able to store stuff into the cache, read from it, but NOT commit to it until some Commit() method is called. Would this be some type of library or pattern I would use?

Comment: You could build a Unit Of Work pattern where you internally queue changes and then execute them all when Commit is called.

Comment: @DavidL all the samples I found have EF "context" in the constructor. I'm not using EF :(

Answer (score 2):

check this class if it helps

Transaction Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction?view=netcore-3.1